# Question related to sigmoid function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, approximation, neural-networks

I have been going through the Deep Learning course from http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

I have come across this approximation in the function $w_jx+b$

$\Delta output \approx \frac {\partial output}{\partial w_j} \Delta w_j + \frac {\partial output}{\partial b}  \Delta b$

I am able to understand why the partial derivative is taken, because to findout the rate of change of the output wrt the bias and weight change

But why the $\Delta w_j$ and $\Delta b$ are being multiplied when approximation is being done as per calculus.

Can you please let me know what kind of approximation method is being used here for obtaining the above equation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a linear approximation of the total change (aka total derivative). The ratio between the change in output vs. the change in $w_j$ multiplied by the total change of $w_j$ should give an approximate change in output based on the change in $w_j$. Same for $b$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Sorry for asking this. Can you please give me the steps how the approximation is done from $output = w_j+b$ to the above equation?

Comment: Just generally, if $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, you can write $\Delta z \approx \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\Delta x + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\Delta y$. That's all that's being used here (because $output$ is a function of $w_j$ and $b$).

Comment: @Siddarth It doesn't matter the function, the sum of the products of partial derivatives and their respective variable changes gives an approximation of the total change to the output. If you think about a function $f(x)$ with one input, it's like estimating how much $f$ changes by doing $f'(x) \cdot \Delta x$

Comment: @AndrewLi: Thanks again as per the Linear Approximation can I think of this $f(output)=w_j$ and we need to find out approximation where $w_j=\Delta w_j$? If that so then $\Delta w_j$ is a real number. like $x=2, for f(x)=logx$ for instance. Please correct me If my understanding is flawed

Comment: It's not really $f(output)=w_j$, rather it is $output = f(w_j, b)$ ($f$ is a function of multiple variables), and you want to estimate the change in $output$ (i.e. $\Delta output$) based on changes in $w_j$ and $b$ (i.e. based on $\Delta w_j$ and $\Delta b$).

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth: After searching through lot in google I could correlate this scenario to local linearity here in local linearity it is said that for any function $f(x)$ where we know what $f(a)$ is and we are trying to find out what $f(b)$ is in that case we try to find the tangent at $f(a)$ and will try to write the equation as $L(x) = f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$, Here I can see the similarity considering $(x-a)$ as nothing but $\Delta a$, is that what was used in the equation mentioned by me as well?

Comment: The $x-a$ is essentially $\Delta x$ ($a$ is like a "reference value" of $x$). In the neural network example, you can think of $\Delta b$ as $b-b^*$ where $b^*$ is some "reference value" of $b$, and $\Delta w_j$ as $w_j - w_j^*$, where $w_j^*$ is a "reference value" of $w_j$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth: Thanks again for the clarification. As per the formula $L(x)=f(a)+f′(a)(x−a)$ then if $(x-a)$ is $\Delta x$ and if $f'(a)$ is $\frac {\partial output}{\partial w_j}$ then what is $f(a)$ here? as per the equation of $\Delta output$?

Comment: Instead, consider the formula $f(x)\approx f(a)+ f'(a)(x-a)$, i.e. $f(x)-f(a)\approx f'(a)(x-a)$. Then $\color{blue}{\Delta f = f(x)-f(a)}$ and so $\Delta f \approx f'(a)\Delta x$. So $\color{blue}{\Delta output = output(w_j,b) - output\left(w_j^*, b^*\right)}$ (i.e. output at $(w_j,b)$, minus output at the "reference" point $\left(w_j^*,b^*\right)$).